# IBM Content Collector error calling external Web Service

Tags: filenet-p8, ibm-content-collector

In my current project using IBM Content Collector 4.0.1 SP5 with IBM Filenet P8 Content Engine 5.2.1 I need to collect files from file system and add them to a certain P8's object store.

After performing upload on the server or in case of error I inserted a WS Call Web Service Task in order to submit some data to be written to a database.

The configuration is the following:
[image]

The web service is REST conformant as requested in the [WS Call Web Service task description page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAE9L_4.0.0/com.ibm.content.collector.doc/task_reference/r_afu_ws_call_service.html#r_afu_ws_call_service__input_mapping) provided by IBM, follows a code excerpt:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filenet/notificaArchiviazione", method = { RequestMethod.GET,
                      RequestMethod.POST }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
                                     MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }, produces = {
                                                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
       @ResponseBody
       String notificaArchiviazione(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName, @RequestParam("esito") String esito) {
```

When ICC tries to call the WS I get a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error like this:

> 2017-10-20T13:47:10.394Z FINEST    [47] Prepared content to send to
>   webservice:{"e:\report\amm_000001_00001\2017\10\201710_amm_000001_00001_qxn_report_00_errato.pdf":{"esito":"KO","fileName":"Prova"},"e:\report\amm_000001_00001\2017\10\201710_amm_000001_00001_qxn_report_00_errato.xml":{"esito":"KO","fileName":"Prova"}}
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask
>   getInputHttpEntity] [CTMS-task-12dc 44] 2017-10-20T13:47:10.456Z
>   FINEST     [48] Configuration:  
>   http://192.168.8.29:8080/sirfAcq/filenet/notificaArchiviazione
>      fileName
>   esito 
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-12dc 44] 2017-10-20T13:47:10.830Z FINEST    [49] Invoking
>   webservice
>   URI:http://192.168.8.29:8080/sirfAcq/filenet/notificaArchiviazione
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-12dc 44] 2017-10-20T13:47:13.763Z FINEST    [50] Invocation
>   took time (ms): 2933
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-12dc 44] 2017-10-20T13:47:13.763Z SEVERE    [51] Failed to
>   invoke webservice: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-12dc 44] 2017-10-20T13:47:13.841Z FINEST    [52]
>   [ctms-native] 2017-10-20T13:47:13Z    Trace2  0x12dc  Invocation
>   successfull, task finished...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it work eliminating the `consumes` parameter from the annotation; doing this will force the WS to accept every kind of possible message provided it is given through a GET or POST method.

In addition I received a [hint by a IBM ICC and eDM L2 support](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/408444/icc-external-ws-call.html#answer-411606) who suggested:

> It appears that your web server does not understand the request that
>   is being sent from ICC.
>
> This is the request being sent from ICC (from the log snippet you
>   provided):
>
> {"e:\report\amm_000001_00001\2017\10\201710_amm_000001_00001_qxn_report_00_errato.pdf":{"esito":"KO","fileName":"Prova"},"e:\report\amm_000001_00001\2017\10\201710_amm_000001_00001_qxn_report_00_errato.xml":{"esito":"KO","fileName":"Prova"}}
>
> Check your code if it is able to parse the data above.