# IBM Content Collector error receiving response after external WS call

Tags: filenet-p8, ibm-content-collector

In my current project using IBM Content Collector 4.0.1 SP5 with IBM Filenet P8 Content Engine 5.2.1 I need to collect files from file system and add them to a certain P8's object store.

This issue is related and comes after [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851328/ibm-content-collector-error-calling-external-web-service/47324705#47324705).

The WS response must conform to a custom metadata source called Esito which contains two metadata properties called `resultCode` and `message`.

The call seems correct but when getting the response I can read this message in the log and the file is not uploaded into P8 Content Manager:

> 2017-11-10T08:54:05.708Z FINEST [52] [ctms-native]
>   2017-11-10T08:54:05Z Trace2 0x15a4 Feeding JavaTask with 1 TaskInputs
>   ufibridge.dll:0x114ac [com.ibm.afu.ufibridge.logging.LoggingAdapter
>   log] [CTMS-task-15a4 45] 2017-11-10T08:54:05.708Z FINEST [53] Prepared
>   content to send to
>   webservice:{"e:\report\amm_000001_00001\2017\11\201711_amm_000001_00001_qxn_report_00.pdf":{"esito":"KO","fileName":"201711_AMM_000001_00001_QXN_REPORT_00(1)(2)(3).pdf"},"e:\report\amm_000001_00001\2017\11\201711_amm_000001_00001_qxn_report_00.xml":{"esito":"KO","fileName":"201711_AMM_000001_00001_QXN_REPORT_00(1)(2)(3).xml"}}
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask
>   getInputHttpEntity] [CTMS-task-15a4 45] 2017-11-10T08:54:05.708Z
>   FINEST [54] Configuration:
>
> property name="message" type="STRING" displayName="message" 
>  
>   property name="resultCode" type="STRING" displayName="resultCode"
>   http://192.168.8.29:8080/sirfAcq/filenet/notificaArchiviazione
>
> fileName esito
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-15a4 45] 2017-11-10T08:54:05.708Z FINEST [55] Invoking
>   webservice
>   URI:http://192.168.8.29:8080/sirfAcq/filenet/notificaArchiviazione
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-15a4 45] 2017-11-10T08:54:05.739Z FINEST [56] Invocation
>   took time (ms): 31
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-15a4 45] 2017-11-10T08:54:05.739Z SEVERE [57]
>   java.lang.String incompatible with com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject
>   [com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask execute]
>   [CTMS-task-15a4 45]Exception [java.lang.ClassCastException]:
>   java.lang.String incompatible with com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject
>   com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask.processResponse(InvokeServiceTask.java:140)
>   com.ibm.afu.connector.webservice.task.InvokeServiceTask.execute(InvokeServiceTask.java:112)

Could someone please explain me the correct format of the WS response JSON?
Could it be possible to use the One-Way mode instead of the Request-Response mode?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to happen because of the incompatibility between the produce and the response body definition, based on the code snippet I had for your first post, your problem should be here:

```
   produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })

   @ResponseBody
   String notificaArchiviazione(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName, @RequestParam("esito") String esito)
```

The first parameter in produce is sat as JSON`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` while in the response body you expect a string `@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName`